# C File updating and creating help

Tags: c

I have two .dat(ascii) files. Both sorted.

1: a clients file containing ; account number , name ,balance
2: a transaction file containing; account number ,date,saleamount(transaction amount)

What i am trying to accomplish is create a new updated clients file which has updated balances for the clients based on adding or subtracting the saleamount of the matching transaction.

My code so far enables me to :

1: if there are not more than one transactions for a client the code runs perfectly writes the .dat file with the clients and their updated balances.

2:if there are more than one transactions for a client my code will run almost perfectly as it will print to the screen the updated clients and accounts for eg:

1 james 540.00
2 john 762.00
3 paul 414.00
4 sam 502.00

will be displayed , but as there are two transactions for john the created .dat file while contain

1 james 540.00
2 john 662.00
2 john 762.00
3 paul 414.00
4 sam 502.00

My problem lies here, I need to find a way of having the created .dat contain only one line for each client ( account number)

My code is attached any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{ 
    int account, matches=0;     /* account number */
    char date[ 30 ]; /* account Date */
    double balance, saleamount,total=0, temp;;  /* account SaleAmount */
    int transaccount;
    char name [ 30 ];
    char lastname[30];
    int lastaccount=-1;
    double lastbalance;



    FILE *cfPtr;     /* cfPtr = clients.dat file pointer */
    FILE *ctPtr;    /* cfPtr = transaction.dat file pointer */
    FILE *cfPtr2;    /* cfPtr2 = new client file */

    cfPtr2 = fopen( "clientupdate.dat", "w" );

    /* fopen opens file; exits program if file cannot be opened */ 
    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "clients.dat", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "clients could not be opened\n" );
        /*fflush(stdin);*/
    } /* end if */
    else
        if( ( ctPtr = fopen( "transactions.dat", "r" ) ) == NULL)
        {
            printf( "File could not be opened\n" );
            /*fflush(stdin);*/
        }
    else { /* read account, date,name, balance and SaleAmount from files */
        fscanf( cfPtr, "%d%s%lf", &account, &name, &balance );
        /*fflush(stdin);*/

        fscanf( ctPtr, "%d%s%lf", &transaccount, &date, &saleamount );
        /*fflush(stdin);*/

        printf( "%-13s%-10s%s\n", "  Account", "Name", "Balance" );
        printf("|----------------------------------|\n");
        while( !feof(ctPtr))
        {   

            while( !feof(cfPtr) &&matches==0 )
            {   
                if(account == transaccount)
                {
                    if (lastaccount != account) {
                    if (lastaccount != -1)
                    printf("  %-10d%-10s%.2lf\n", lastaccount, lastname, lastbalance);
                    lastaccount = account;
                    strcpy (lastname, name);
}

                    matches=1;
                    total=0;
                    temp = balance+saleamount;
                    total = total + temp;
                    balance = total; 
                    lastbalance = balance;
                }
                else
                {

                    fscanf( cfPtr, "%d%s%lf", &account, &name, &balance );
                    /*fflush(stdin);*/
                }   

            }
            fprintf( cfPtr2, "%d %s %.2lf\n", account, name, total );
            fscanf( ctPtr, "%d%s%lf", &transaccount, &date, &saleamount );
            /*fflush(stdin);*/
           matches=0;

        }
    }
       if (lastaccount != -1)
    printf("  %-10d%-10s%.2lf\n", lastaccount, lastname, lastbalance);
        fclose( cfPtr2 );
        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a well made homework question. You wrote some code, and explained to us what you wrote. We don't see many good homework questions around here :)

Comment: @earlz I'm Studying this in college,The way i look at it is if i don't explain it right / even attempt as much as i can i wont learn if by chance someone does help me.

Answer (score 1):

As promised, here is a quick exmaple of a father-son update.  I have not bothered checking for file opening errors as you already have them in your code, and a real application would need to check more than just EOF for fscanf in order to detect invalid file formatting.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define bool int
#define false 0
#define true !false

#define MAX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER 99999

typedef struct
{
 int accountNumber;
 char accountName[30];
 float accountTotal;
} ClientRecordType;

typedef struct
{
 int accountNumber;
 char transactionDate[30];
 float transactionAmount;
} TransactionRecordType;

FILE *oldClientFile;
FILE *newClientFile;
FILE *transactionFile;


void getNextClient(FILE *p_clientFile, ClientRecordType *p_clientRecord)
{
 if (EOF == fscanf(p_clientFile, "%d%s%f", 
                   &p_clientRecord->accountNumber,
                   &p_clientRecord->accountName,
                   &p_clientRecord->accountTotal))
   p_clientRecord->accountNumber = MAX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
}


void getNextTransaction(FILE *p_transactionFile,
                        TransactionRecordType *p_transactionRecord)
{
 if (EOF == fscanf(p_transactionFile, "%d%s%f", 
                   &p_transactionRecord->accountNumber,
                   &p_transactionRecord->transactionDate,
                   &p_transactionRecord->transactionAmount))
   p_transactionRecord->accountNumber = MAX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
}


void writeUpdatedClientRecord(FILE *p_newClientFile,
                              ClientRecordType *p_clientRecord)
{
 fprintf(p_newClientFile, "%d %s %.2f ",
         p_clientRecord->accountNumber,
         p_clientRecord->accountName,
         p_clientRecord->accountTotal);
} 


bool performTransactionUpdate(FILE *p_oldClientFile,
                              FILE *p_newClientFile,
                              FILE *p_transactionFile)
{
 ClientRecordType clientRecord;
 TransactionRecordType transactionRecord;

 getNextClient(p_oldClientFile, &clientRecord);
 getNextTransaction(p_transactionFile, &transactionRecord);
 while (MAX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER != clientRecord.accountNumber)
 {
  if (clientRecord.accountNumber == transactionRecord.accountNumber)
  {
   clientRecord.accountTotal += transactionRecord.transactionAmount;
   getNextTransaction(p_transactionFile, &transactionRecord);
  }
  else if (clientRecord.accountNumber < transactionRecord.accountNumber)
  {
   writeUpdatedClientRecord(p_newClientFile, &clientRecord);
   getNextClient(p_oldClientFile, &clientRecord);
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
 }
 if (MAX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER != transactionRecord.accountNumber) return false;
 return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 oldClientFile = fopen("clients.dat", "r");
 newClientFile = fopen("newclients.dat", "w");
 transactionFile = fopen("transactions.dat", "r");

 if (performTransactionUpdate(oldClientFile,
                              newClientFile,
                              transactionFile))
   printf("\nUpdate completed without errors!\n");
 else
   printf("\nUnsorted files or invalid transactions encountered\n");

 close(newClientFile);
 close(oldClientFile);
 close(transactionFile);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach would be to load the client file into memory, process the transaction file against each client, and then dump the client data back to disk.

If you prefer to do things the old way, you could of course sort the transaction file into client order prior to processing.

Comment: @taliadon the transaction file is already sorted into client order 

to give the results i posted it contains 

1    26/06/1991 200.00 

2    21/10/1251 212.00

2   12/12/1212  100.00 

3   14/05/2100 214.00
 
4   24/19/2021 152.00 

the program gets the balance right when printing to the screen and only prints it once, but when outputting to the file it contains 2 lines for client 2 as it had two transactions

Comment: I assume the client file is already sorted?  If not, then sort this too prior to processing.

Comment: All transactions should therefore occur in a single block; once the client name changes in the transaction file, there can be no more entries for this client.  At this point, it is safe to output the client total.

Comment: Yeah theyre both sorted, everything works fine just apart from it writing both updates to the file rather than the cumulative update for the client using the 2 or more transactions for it. basically i want what is printed on the screen ( which is correct) to be what is in the newfile too.

Comment: Say the current client file is Andrew=900, David=300, John=400, Lisa=0; and the transaction file is John +300, John -200, Lisa +200.

Comment: Well the matching occurs with account number but the output of that on my screen would give me :

andrew 900,
david 300,
john 500,
lisa 200,

but into the file would be :
andrew 900,
david 300,
john 700,
john 500,
lisa 200,

can you see what i mean??

Comment: Read the first line of each file and compare the names: first transaction is for John.  As files are sorted, there can be no transactions for Andrew.  Output Andrew as is to new client file and read next client from old file.  Same thing happens for David.  When you get to John, the names match so apply transaction.  Read next transaction.  This also applies to John, so again apply transaction.  Read next transaction.  This time the transaction applies to Lisa, so there can be no more transactions for John.  Now output Johns tally to new client file, and read next client.

Comment: Continue until both files are processed.

Comment: I understand your logic completely , figuring out what/where to edit my code to this though i dont think im competent enough to do but shall give it a go, Appreciate the help.

Comment: In the old days of sequential tape processing, this kind of transaction was known as a father-son update.  You could try and search for an example of this on the web, but I fear it is likely to be in COBOL :)  I have to go to work now, but I'll post a code clippet later if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: Yeah my lecturer has not thought C in like 10+ years so he's using old examples which in turn become confusing, appreciate that man.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the help of an answer posted and a fellow student coming up with this working code. Thank for helping me to figure out how to get this working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{ 
    int account;     /* account number */
    char date[ 30 ]; /* account Date */
    double balance, saleamount; /* account SaleAmount */
    int transaccount;
    char name [ 30 ];
    int newaccount;
    char newname[ 30];
    double newbalance;
    int match=0;



    FILE *cfPtr;     /* cfPtr = clients.dat file pointer */
    FILE *ctPtr;    /* cfPtr = transaction.dat file pointer */
    FILE *cfPtr2;    /* cfPtr2 = new client file */

    cfPtr2 = fopen( "clientupdate.dat", "w" );

    /* fopen opens file; exits program if file cannot be opened */ 
    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "clients.dat", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "clients could not be opened\n" );

    } /* end if */
    else
        if( ( ctPtr = fopen( "transactions.dat", "r" ) ) == NULL)
        {
            printf( "File could not be opened\n" );

        }
    else { /* read account, date,name, balance and SaleAmount from files */
        fscanf( cfPtr, "%d%s%lf", &account, &name, &balance );


        fscanf( ctPtr, "%d%s%lf", &transaccount, &date, &saleamount );
        fscanf( cfPtr2, "%d%s%lf", &newaccount, &newname, &newbalance );
        while ( !feof( cfPtr ) )
        {
            transaccount=1;
            newbalance=balance;
            while ( !feof( ctPtr ) )
            {
                if(transaccount==account&&match==0)
                {
                 newbalance = balance + saleamount;
                 match++;
                }
                else
                    if(transaccount==account&&match>0)
                     newbalance = newbalance + saleamount;

                fscanf( ctPtr, "%d%s%lf", &transaccount, date, &saleamount );
            }
            rewind( ctPtr);
            match=0;

        fprintf( cfPtr2, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, newbalance );
        fscanf( cfPtr, "%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance );
        }

        rewind( cfPtr2);
    }
        fclose( cfPtr2 );
        fclose( cfPtr );
        fclose( ctPtr );
        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```